# Unit testing a bash script calling mount partition

Tags: bash, unit-testing, mocking, shunit2

I have a bash script that calls linux `mount`.

I want to unit test that script. I'm currently using [shunit2](https://github.com/kward/shunit2).

One thing that I tried was to create a file `mount` and tried to use this one to respond 0 or -1 or +1 depending on what I wanted to test.

It obviously didn't work :)

Is there a way to make it work? Any suggestions?

Comment: Wow. Didn't even know that there was a unit testing framework for shell. Excuse me while I unit test all my scripts. We will probably need the problematic code to make any sort of suggestions though...

Comment: I kind of already solved the problem. As soon I arrive at my desk on Monday, I will post the answer here.

Answer (score 0):

I would create a mock for the mount command this way:

```
mount() {
  return $DESIRED_MOUNT_RETURN_CODE
}

setUp() {
  export DESIRED_MOUNT_RETURN_CODE=0 # default
}

testMountSucceeds() {
  . $script_under_test > /dev/null
  ...
}

testMountFails() {
  export DESIRED_MOUNT_RETURN_CODE=1
  . $script_under_test > /dev/null
  ...
}

. shunit2
```